# How to display progress from an Ajax call using a custom PHP function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call that is processing some data and the length of time it takes varies widely depending on the site. I'd like to set a progress value in the PHP function doing the processing (I'm assuming to a SESSION variable).

While that is processing, I'd like to have another loop that is running and fetching the SESSION variable value every second or so and updating the user on what % is complete as it goes along.

So my main Ajax call to process the data is working and takes place when the user clicks a button. This is in WordPress, so the call looks something like this -

```
function get_data(refresh){
        $.post({
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    beforeSend:function(){
                        $("#loader-gif").show();
                    },
                    complete:function(){
                        $("#loader-gif").hide();
                    },
                    data: { refresh: refresh, action: "refresh_data"},
                    success:function(data){
                      $("#loader-gif").hide();
                      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                          alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                          $("#loader-gif").hide();
                        }
            });
    }
```

What do I need to add to this in order to loop as this is running and update a span/div on the page from a PHP session variable?

This is the only Ajax call on the page currently and will likely remain so.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link for an progress bar:

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/progress-indicator-for-an-ajax-request/100083

Comment: That looks to be a broken example for which the original author never received a response that resolved his issue.